Hilbert system: Proof of several theorems
I was asked to prove the following:

$$\vdash_L\ \neg q\to(p\to p)$$
$$\vdash_L\ p\to(q\to (\neg q\to q))$$
Additionally, assuming hypothetical syllogism($p\to q,q\to r\vdash_L p\to r$) and $(\neg p\to p)\to p$, show that $\vdash_L\ p\to \neg\neg p$.

The axioms provided are:

$$p\to(q\to p)$$
$$p\to(q\to r)\to((p\to q)\to(p\to r)$$
$$(\neg p\to \neg q)\to(q\to p)$$

I believe only substitution and modus ponens can be used. In (1), I managed to prove (p \to p), but I am unsure how to "add" an antecedent.

An instance of the first axiom is $(p\to p) \to (\lnot q\to (p\to p)).$

@spaceisdarkgreen Oh, that makes sense! It looks like the same trick can be easily applied to the proof of Theorem 2. Thanks!
